# Agents moving in attractors

Tags: anylogic

I have a problem with attractors in Anylogic. If I have a rectangular node  with some attractors and I send some agents(pallets in my case ) on this attractors they Will move between the attractors. Instead  each pallet Have to stay in the initial attractor until I decide to move them in another place. Can anyone help me? 
Thank 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyrNp.png)

Comment: this is because you are sending your pallets to the node.. instead you have to move them to the attractor you want to

Comment: But the problem in this case is that I have 6 pallets that I move with a move to block. I don't know if I can specify in the move to destination the 6 attractors that are in the rectangular node. I've tried to do what you say but I can specify only one attractor in the move to destination.

Comment: of course you can... in the destination options on the moveTo block there is "Attractor" as an option

Comment: But as you can see in the image that I've linked, In the "Quality control zone" there are 6 attractors. Instead in the moveTo destination option I can specify only one of this six attractor as destination!

Comment: you need to specify your problem more clearly... you make one moveTo with the initial attractor and then when you need to move the pallet again you use another move to with a different attractor.... What is wrong with doing that?

Comment: ok I'll try to be clearer. I use 1 move to block to move 6 pallets to the quality control zone (so I have six attractors in this area). Here I simulate (using a delay) the operation of checking one pallet at a time. Each pallet after being checked must be stored in another area (so here I will use a move to and a rackstore).

Comment: However, my problem is in the quality control area, because every time a pallet leaves this area the pallets that have yet to be checked move incredibly from one attractor to another of the Q.C. area, instead each pallet should remain stationary in the initial attractor until it is checked. I hope I have been clearer now :)

Comment: in that case you need to show the model you are using, because it is obviously wrong

Comment: and you need to show exactly what's inside the blocks that you are using